# Scala compilation error: Required: Future[S_] Found: String

Tags: scala, future

The following function should get a code block execute it and return future with corresponding message response.
I get compilation error says: Required: Future[S_] Found: String, can someone explain why?

```
def withTransaction(blockOfCode: => Future[User])(implicit transaction: Transaction[User]): Future[String] = Future {

  println("WithTransaction called...")

  blockOfCode.flatMap(_ => {
    transaction.commit()
    "Success"
  }).recover { // here is the error
    transaction.rollback()
    "Failed"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Future#recover`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html#recover%5BU%3E:T%5D(pf:PartialFunction%5BThrowable,U%5D)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future%5BU%5D) expects a *partial function*

```
def recover[U >: T](pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, U])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[U] =
```

which can be expressed using curly brackets and case syntax like so

```
{ case e => expression }
```

however since `e` is not used we might as well use *discarded parameter* function syntax, as per jwvh's comment,

```
_ => expression
```

In your particular case it does not really matter which one you choose, but in general partial function would allow you to, say, have different types of recovery mechanisms per different types of error

```
{ 
  case e: SocketTimeoutException => // recovery mechanism A 
  case e: ArithmeticException   =>  // recovery mechanism B
  case ...
}
```

Furthermore you likely need `map` instead of `flatMap` because you are mapping to `"Success"` instead of `Future("Success")`. Consider the difference between

```
Future(42).map(_ => "hello")              // ok
Future(42).flatMap(_ => "hello")          // error
Future(42).flatMap(_ => Future("hello"))  // ok
```

Putting it together try

```
def withTransaction(
  blockOfCode: => Future[User]
)(implicit transaction: Transaction[User]): Future[String] = {
  blockOfCode
    .map { _ =>
      transaction.commit()
      "Success"
    }.recover { _ =>
      transaction.rollback()
      "Failed"
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better to write all method entirely cause the `Future` in start of method could confuse author of question.

Comment: If `e` is unused then `_ =>` should be sufficient.

Comment: I'm now getting: "Required: Future[String], Found: Future[Future[String]]"

Comment: @AmirLasry Did you remove the `Future` after `=` sign?

Comment: Just did it and it works, can you please explain why?

Comment: @AmirLasry Consider the type of `Future(blockOfCode)`. Because `blockOfCode` is already a `Future` then wrapping it in another `Future` makes the type `Future[Future[A]]`, hence there is no need for additional wrapping, especially since return type of `withTransaction` is expected to be `Future[A]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216317/discussion-between-mario-galic-and-amir-lasry).